# What is the purpose of each file in the React Native file architecture?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile-development

I started to use React Native recently and, following the oficial docs, I initialized a project using `npx react-native init ProjectName`.

I'm not sure if the tools versions matters (probably yes), but i'm using `npm version 6.13.7`, `react-native-cli version 2.0.1` and `react-native 0.62.2`. With that config, the file architecture i that get is the following:

[image: react native file architeture]

I seached about it, but i not found an answer. So, can someone please explain to me what is the purpose of each file in this file architecture and which of these files can i remove?

Thank you in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Package.json**

This file holds all of the dependencies of modules that your app is using and needed to install for running your app.

**yarn.lock files yarn and package-lock.json**

These two files hold the version of your dependencies **yarn.lock package-lock.json** is automatically generated for any operations where npm or yarn modifies either the node_modules tree or package.json. It describes the exact tree that was generated, such that subsequent installs are able to generate identical trees, regardless of intermediate dependency updates.

**app.json**

This file holds your application name etc.

**babel.config.js**

This file holds configs related to babel, Babels is a transpiler that transpile ES6 to ES5.

**index.js**

This is the entry point of your application form where your react-native code start executing.

**EsLint and Prettier**

These file related to maintaining the code indentation, Unused imports, extra, spacing, these files holds configs related to these things(EsLint and prettier are used to avoid above-mentioned things).

**.watchMan**

watchman watches the code changes when the packager is running, so this file have configs about this.

**.Flow**

Flow is been used for type checking so it holds the configs related to this.

**node_modules**

This folder holds all of the modules that your app is been using also lited down in your `package.json`.

And then there is `Android`(which holds native android code), `IOS`(which holds native ios code), and other `JS files` which holds code react-native js code.

Comment: Thank you so much, bro. Your help clarified a lot.

Comment: No problem bro.